# Property is null after binding using FromRoute attribute on a POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have an endpoint decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute.
This endpoint url should have one of it's input object's properties coming from the route itself but all other properties should come from the request body.

This is the endpoint decorated with it's routing definition:

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("{userId}/orders/add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserOrderCreationRequest>> CreateOrder(
           [FromBody]RequestObject request)
```

The request object have a property defined like this:

```
 public class RequestObject
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public Order order { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason the UserId is not getting populated and is coming null.

BUT, when I change the `[FromBody]` to `[FromQuery]` it is working well.

I have also tried removing the `[FromBody]` without any replacement and it still didn't work as I got UserId equals null.

Can someone explain this behavior? Why only the
`[FromQuery]` gets it to work?
Any other solution that doesn't include creating `CustomBinder` will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you call this endpoint - from form submit or from ajax?

Comment: It's an API of a microservice, being called from other microservices.

Comment: Thanks, then remove [frombody] and use  application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I have found a way to deal with it but it works only with .NET 6 and above. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217544/how-to-parameter-binding-from-multiple-sources/74323145#74323145

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `RequestObject` class - you're doing something very weird for binding data.

Instead, bind two different parameters in your `CreateOrder` method.

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("{userId}/orders/add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserOrderCreationRequest>> CreateOrder(
    string userId, // [FromRoute] is optional here
    [FromBody] Order order)
{

}
```

Comment: Why is this binding considered wired? I actually consider the need to split to two parameters just because they come from different source (body/route/query..) wired (again, without customizing the binder). It's also wired that it DOES working when I just add the [FromQuery] attribute. And according to @Serge answer above, since my clients are calling my endpoint using application/json content-type, and I don't like the solution of splitting to another parameter, I guess I'll just add the [FromQuery] although it doesn't really make any sense to me (hopefully, this will pass code-review :-))

Comment: This solution shows you the most promoted pattern from Microsoft's documentation. You're free to use Serge's solution if it works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content type. You must be using application/json content type. In this case you will need to put userId separately and add [FromBody] attribute

```
[Route("{userId}/orders/add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserOrderCreationRequest>> CreateOrder(string userId,[FromBody] Order order)
```

but if you use application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data form enctype or ajax content-type  then this will be working if you remove [FromBody] attribute

```
[Route("{userId}/orders/add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserOrderCreationRequest>> CreateOrder( Order order)
```

and in this  case you don't need fromquery or fromroute

```
public class RequestObject
{
     public string UserId { get; set; }

    public Order order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Serge, How do you explain that it works well just by changing the FromBody to FromQuery? I have tried it with also a custom header and a query string parameters and it seems all parameter are getting the binding as expected (route, query, body, header). I just don't understand what the FromQuery has that the FromBody hasn't.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to fool the ASP.NET input formatters:

```
[HttpPost]    
[Route("{request.UserId}/orders/add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserOrderCreationRequest>> CreateOrder([FromRoute] RequestObject request)
```

```
public class RequestObject
{
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  [FromBody]
  public Order order { get; set; }
}
```